# How to fix or freeze a column in lightning data table

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning data table with lot of columns specified. First column in the table is called **Product** and there are other columns. In order to update other columns user has to scroll the table for it but the problem is when they scroll right user is not able to understand for which **Product** they are updating the other columns. Product column being the key column.. Is there a way we can make it fixed or is there anyway to show for which product they are making changes when updating other columns.. Any pointers are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

No. You'll have to make a custom data table from the [blueprints](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/). It's not too bad, it only took me a few hours to scrape together what I needed the last time I made such a table from the blueprints (but it also wasn't feature complete). Or, you can try customizing the one from [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components), as it is open source.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Instead of redesigning the whole component.. Is there any workaround like showing Product Value dynamically for each of the rows somewhere in the table like a tool tip or on a hover or showing it as another column outside the table.